# Modifying a C# Bitmap in an external DLL

Tags: c#, windows, bitmap, gdi

I need to process an image which is provided by a C# program as a `Bitmap` object. The processing is performed in a C++ DLL, which receives a handle to a GDI object (`HBITMAP`) created from the Bitmap, via

```
Bitmap.GetHbitmap();
```

The argument passing between C# and the DLL works fine, and the GDI object has the expected characteristics. I can read the pixels of the image, in the DLL.

Anyway, when I try to modify the image via the DLL, the change is not reflected in the C# application, as if the image was read-only. I suspect that some operation must be performed to convert back from the GDI object to the `Bitmap` instance, but I see nothing in the .NET API.

I am aware of the `LockBits/UnlockBits` mechanism, which I could probably use if nothing else works, but my current requirement is to pass a Handle only.

Any hint ?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [**`Image.FromHbitmap()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k061we7x(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @VisualVincent Yesss! This is what I needed, it works. You can enter this as an answer I guess.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [**`Image.FromHbitmap()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k061we7x(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Using it you will be able to convert from a `HBITMAP` into a .NET `Bitmap`.

```
Bitmap bmp = Image.FromHbitmap(<HBITMAP pointer here>);
```

Comment: The raster data is indeed duplicated and needs to be copied back. I would have preferred a direct acces to the buffer of the .NET Bitmap, but I am afraid this is not pssible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Well I'm not aware of any method of doing so, so I guess not.